# How to hack LiveScript in order to link a separate file in html

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, livescript

We could include separate coffee-script file in html with:

```
<script type="text/coffeescript" src="/static/webpage.coffee"></script>
```

But if we want to use LiveScript in browser, they say:

> If you use this, your LiveScript scripts must be inline (not linked to with the src attribute), be placed after the included livescript.js file, and the script tags must have the attribute type="text/ls".

I need exact same include technique we used to use for coffee-script or Javascript. So, is there anyone give me a tip to start hacking?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way at all? You really should be converting your CoffeeScript and LiveScript to JavaScript yourself rather than making your users do it over and over again.

Comment: It's for debugging purposes. Writing code in one language and debugging in another is a hard job to manage. I needed the error messages in browser for LiveScript, not for Javascript. For production code, you are totally right.

Comment: There are `.map` files to help with debugging. That approach also means that you'll be debugging exactly the same stuff that you're deploying.

Comment: Relevant code in [CoffeeScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/f96ab11febc3bf67b2d6b2a56c35febf7e0cfbc9/src/browser.coffee#L56) and [LiveScript](https://github.com/gkz/LiveScript/blob/c2bc68ba32940b934d58c27a1801cad618a19fc8/browser/livescript.js#L8925). Looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `LiveScript.go()` in [*src/browser.ls*](https://github.com/gkz/LiveScript/blob/c2bc68ba32940b934d58c27a1801cad618a19fc8/src/browser.ls#L29) ([*browser/livescript.js*](https://github.com/gkz/LiveScript/blob/c2bc68ba32940b934d58c27a1801cad618a19fc8/browser/livescript.js#L8936))  it is apparent that external files are actually supported. Indeed, the following worked for me:

```
<head>
    <script src="livescript-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/ls" src="script.ls"></script>
    <script>
        require('LiveScript').go();
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Worked for me too... I'm wondering if there is any case that couses this method don't work.

Comment: It's `require('livescript')` in new versions.